# jquery .click() is not registering an event listener when I start my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML page and an accompanyish javascript file. I want to trigger some javascript code when the user clicks on an image in a table. I added a jquery .click() function and I call that also from document.ready, but when I load the page I cannot click on the image. If I open F12 and manually write the jquery .click(), it becomes enabled, the eventlistener is registered, and I can click on the image to trigger the code. But not when just loading the page from IntelliJ.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpage.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http_code.jquery.com_jquery-2.0.0.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="profile.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is my main page</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="image1">
                <img src="images/fluffcat.jpg" align="left"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><img src="images/midsommarcat.jpg" align="center" id="image2"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/tortillacat.jpg" align="right" id="image3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cat 1</td>
        <td>Cat 2</td>
        <td>Cat 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript file:

```
/**
 * Created by jlg on 2016-06-11.
 */
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello World")
}

function doClick() {
    alert("something happened!");
    window.open("Profile", "Profile", "", false);
}

function openPopup() {
    console.log("I got here at least");
    $("#image1").click(doClick);
}

function documentReadyFunctions() {
    sayHello();
    openPopup();
}

$( document ).ready(documentReadyFunctions());
```

What am I missing here? Is there some sort of ordering in the javascript file I'm missing? The "console.log("I got here at least");" shows up in the Console, as well as Hello World.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code,

```
$(document).ready(documentReadyFunctions());
```

`documentReadyFunctions()` will call the function immediately and assign the returned value as callback to the `ready`.

And as the `script` is loaded in the `<head>`, by the time when this function is executed, the elements are not available in the DOM.

**Remove the `()` invocation of the function.**

```
$(document).ready(documentReadyFunctions);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   // Don't call it, pass the function reference.
```

This will pass the function as reference and the function will be called when the DOM is ready.